# Finding all entities changed in one context and add it to another context

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework

We have a main thread which spawns multiple worker thread. The input to each spawned thread is a entity framework context (newly created object having no data). Inside each thread we will try to fetch data from different tables and try to update the changes in entity framework context object that is passed as an input parameter. Before thread finishes this entity framework context object will be returned to the main thread.

In the main thread we will have a `mainEFContext` object which will accumulate the changes from all the threads and saves the changes for every X minutes. Is there a way to identify all the entities that each thread has in one go? As of now I am iterating over all tables and finding their count and then adding that object from thread context to `mainThreadContext`. But I feel there should be a better way of doing these things..

Also the thread context has `AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false` to save the performance. I think it shouldn't matter if I detach the object from thread context and attach it to the `MainThreadContext` even though `AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false` in thread context.

Comment: I found "threadContex.ChangeTracker.Entries()" which gives me changed entries but how to add these to the mainEFContext?